# How and when does a parent class get instantiated in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, instance, self

In Python3 I assumed that the creation of a class with a parent causes the parent class to be instantiated. This code shows it does not work like that.

```
class AClass:
    def __init__(self):
    print("make A")
    self.val = True
def f(self):
    return self.val

class BClass(AClass):
    def __init__(self):
        print("make B")
        self.val = False
    def g(self):
        return self.val

b = BClass()
print(b.f())
print(b.g())
```

The output is

```
make B
False
False
```

The output shows `AClass.__init__(self)` is not called and the function `f` uses the self value created in `BClass`. If an `AClass` instance existed then the `g` function would have returned `True`.

I'm learning Python and I find this behavior very counterintuitive. What I want is to have a `self` instance variable at every level in the inheritance hierarchy. Is this not normal in Python3? If there were `self` instances in the inheritance tree would a method name follow the regular inheritance rules? Does Python do something else to implement what I want?

Comment: You should first fix your indentation in the posted code...

Comment: _"What I want is to have a self instance variable at every level in the inheritance hierarchy."_ What does that even mean? When you instantiate a class you get __one__ object, not one for each class in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call the init function of the parent you want to use :

```
Super(self, BClass).__init__()
```

Basically calling the parent class of the current instance (Thus sending the type of the instance of the class, and the currently instantiated class - self).

Also I dont find this counter intuitive, you over-writed the init function of the parent.